# Redact passwords before logging

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to hide passwords from a string with regex before logging

$ cat rubytest.rb

```
str = 'login=luser-name&password=secretpw&otherstuff=dontcare'
print "1: ",str.sub(/password=.+(?<post>(&.+))/,'password=<redacted>\k<post>'),"\n"
print "2: ",str.sub(/password=.+(?<post>(&.+)?)/,'password=<redacted>\k<post>'),"\n"

str = 'login=luser-name&password=secretpw'
print "3: ",str.sub(/password=.+(?<post>(&.+))/,'password=<redacted>\k<post>'),"\n"
print "4: ",str.sub(/password=.+(?<post>(&.+)?)/,'password=<redacted>\k<post>'),"\n"
```

$ ruby rubytest.rb

```
1: login=luser-name&password=<redacted>&otherstuff=dontcare
2: login=luser-name&password=<redacted>
3: login=luser-name&password=secretpw
4: login=luser-name&password=<redacted>
```

1: works if str got more data than password to redact,
2: redacts to EoL not intended,
3: doesn't redact at all,
4: works when password is last item in str

How can I combine regex 1 & 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, except if `&` cannot be a password character. In that case:

```
/password=[^&]+(?<post>(&.+)?)/
```

Anyway if it is in a url you *will* have to transcode the ampersand.

Comment: & in passwords will be encoded, & is the http parameter separator

Comment: You are welcome. Don't hesitate to accept the answer :-) Cheers